# ignoring certain elements in a nested list

Tags: python, web-scraping, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have the following list

```
[["abc","cdf","efgh","x","hijk","y","z"],["xyz","qwerty","uiop","x","asdf","y","z"]]
```

I would like to have the following output

```
[["abc","cdf","efgh","hijk"],["xyz","qwerty","uiop","asdf"]]
```

How can I perform the splitting operation here?
PS: The original data is pretty large.
Original data : http://pasted.co/20f85ce5

Comment: What's the relationship between the input and output? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Note that this is a `filter` operation, not a `split`.

Comment: I am trying to web scrape certain data from a website. Using Selenium, I was able to extract the data in a nested list. My problem is that I am not interested in certain elements of the nested list.

Comment: But what decides which elements are you not interested in? Is it length 1 strings? etc..

Comment: @chrisz If you follow the link, in the given data, I am not interested in the last 9 elements starting from "follow" to "compare". I would like to remove all those 9 elements from each nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a nested list comprehension for your task.

```
old = [["abc","cdf","efgh","x","hijk","y","z"],["xyz","qwerty","uiop","x","asdf","y","z"]]

droplist = ["x", "y", "z"]
new = [[item for item in sublist if item not in droplist] for sublist in old]
print(new)
```

Note the creation of the `new` list. The outer list comprehnsion considers each of the sublists. The inner list comprehension considers individual strings.

The filter occurs when `if item not in droplist` is executed.

The `if item not in droplist` can be replaced by any criteria you can code. For example:

```
new = [[item for item in sublist if len(item) >= 3] for sublist in old]
```

Or even:

```
def do_I_like_it(s):
    # Arbitrary code to decide if `s` is worth keeping
    return True
new = [[item for item in sublist if do_I_like_it(item)] for sublist in old]
```

If you want to remove items by their location in the sublists, use slicing:

```
# Remove last 2 elements of each sublist
new = [sublist[:-2] for sublist in old]
assert new == [['abc', 'cdf', 'efgh', 'x', 'hijk'], ['xyz', 'qwerty', 'uiop', 'x', 'asdf']]
```

Comment: Would it be faster to have droplist be a set?

Comment: Not for small groups, I think.